# jdbc connection on tomcat server

Tags: apache, tomcat, jdbc, connection

I will try to formulate as best as I can.

First, web application(Spring MVC with Spring Jdbc) worked well until I started messing out with versions of STS(Spring Tool Suite based on Eclipse) and JDK+JRE7 to get features of Java 7.

Second, the current problem is that Apache Tomcat 6 or 7(I have both which I reinstalled for reason I don't remember) seems to be affecting the connection to the database. Saying directly: it fails to get jdbc connection

```
 org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql:postgres
```

and it happens whenever I try to do any operation on database from my web application.

The line jdbc:postgresql:postgres is OK just in case, because it worked before and it effectively says to connect to local database with name postgres(and also because of the point below).

Another important point to mention is that under vFabric tc Server everything works flawlessly without any problems whatsoever.

Third, the database is PostgreSql along with Apache DBCP pooling.

Fourth, the maven jdbc driver dependencies seems to work well, as again if they didn't vFabric tc Server would also fail same as Apache Tomcat which leads to me to an idea that Apache Tomcat is itself the culprit.

Some of the information produced during server start-up:

```
     Dec 14, 2011 4:54:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
     INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal                       performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path:           C:\ProgramFiles\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.0.3\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;.
     Dec 14, 2011 4:54:32 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
     INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
     Dec 14, 2011 4:54:32 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
     INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
     Dec 14, 2011 4:54:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
     INFO: Initialization processed in 849 ms
     Dec 14, 2011 4:54:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServicestartInternal
     INFO: Starting service Catalina
     Dec 14, 2011 4:54:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
     INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.23
     Dec 14, 2011 4:54:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
     INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Users\User\Documents\workspace-sts\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\conf\Catalina\localhost\project.xml
     Dec 14, 2011 4:54:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin
     WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:project' did not find a matching property.
     Dec 14, 2011 4:54:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
     INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext

     Dec 14, 2011 4:54:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
     INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
     Dec 14, 2011 4:54:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
     INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
     Dec 14, 2011 4:54:37 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
     INFO: Server startup in 4664 ms
```

I am really desperate please help.

**UPDATE:**

Still sitting in front looking at sad screen, so I decided to include all the .xml configuration.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource">
    <constructor-arg ref="connectionPool"/>
</bean>

<bean id ="connectionPool" class="org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool">
<constructor-arg><null/></constructor-arg>
</bean>


<bean id="poolableConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory" >
<constructor-arg ref="connectionFactory"/>
<constructor-arg ref="connectionPool"/>
<constructor-arg><null/></constructor-arg>
<constructor-arg><null/></constructor-arg>
<constructor-arg value="false"/>
<constructor-arg value="true"/>
</bean>

    <bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverManagerConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg value="jdbc:postgresql:postgres"/>
    <constructor-arg value="postgres"/>
    <constructor-arg value="myCorrectPassword"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: How are you loading the drivers?

Comment: Wiring in spring configuration file, do you want me to post it?

Comment: Check that eclipse is copying the jar to the work folder (somewhere under the .settings folder). If you really need to make progress, just put the jar in the common lib folder and set the dependency as <scope>provided</scope>

Comment: I checked the target folders and .war file produced. They have included jar inside. It is as again I am saying if these were the problems then vFabric Server wouldnt work either? Maybe I am wrong I don't know anything anymore. I know how to code, but setting up is always place where I waste my time.

Answer (score 2):

In grl, I'd say that DB drivers should probably go into the common lib folder on Tomcat.
Usually those drivers are used for several applications.

Additionally, if you set your pool in the context.xml, this is required.

Comment: @Aubergine I'm going to second what this guy said

Comment: Well, I have done as you said. (though I don't personally remember doing that before) But it still doesnt work, I included exact same version as in maven dependencies, same jar, in tomcat/lib. Oh, I am getting so sad.

Comment: The problem is probably Eclipse. Try adding the entry to the classpath (on the Tomcat conf window). I just tried and it worked. So, the application context is ok. Can you post your postgresql dependency? I used (Spring 3.0.6.RELEASE):
<dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: Seems to be the problem in application context, I really don't know how or why. But as you can see I don't indicate anywhere what kind of vendor driver I load. In Connection factory I have only URL Name and Pass. Plus I tried to connect to db from other Spring MVC application working on tomcat using basic configuration using simple data source and it worked(without even giving the dependency in maven). I will post my solution today.

Comment: Since you put the library on tomcat/lib you don't to need the dependency on maven. But, in that case I'd suggest to set it as provided anyways. I don't think you need to indicate the driver. Drivers are being registered some how.... Using your context I get a "Connection refused" (because I don't have postgres) but, I do see on the stack trace the correct Driver/Connection.
One last check might be to package the solution and deploy it manually on tomcat. Just to be 100% sure it's a eclipse problem or not.